# DevOps error while executing mvn -version or mvn commands in ubuntu

Tags: devops

I had been trying to resolve this but it shows the same every time but my environment is all good even though it throws the error please suggest me how to clear this 
mvn -version

> /usr/bin/mvn: 1: /usr/bin/mvn: uname: not found Error: JAVA_HOME is
>   not defined correctly. We cannot execute
>   /home/dpu/distros/jdk1.8.0_181/bin/bin/java

Comment: Are you sure that `/home/dpu/distros/jdk1.8.0_181/bin/bin/java` exists and is executable? Can you provide us with output of `echo $JAVA_HOME` ?

Comment: echo $JAVA_HOME
/home/deepu/distros/jdk-10.0.2
this is what i got

Comment: And what `ls /home/dpu/distros/jdk1.8.0_181/bin/bin/java` returns?